# R - how to exclude pennystocks from environment before calculating adjusted stock returns

Tags: r, environment, xts, yahoo-finance, quantmod

Within my current research I'm trying to find out, how big the impact of ad-hoc sentiment on daily stock returns is.
Calculations functioned quite well and results also are plausible.
The calculations until now with quantmod package and yahoo financial data look like below:

```css
getSymbols(c("^CDAXX",Symbols) , env = myenviron, src = "yahoo",
           from = as.Date("2007-01-02"), to = as.Date("2016-12-30")

Returns <- eapply(myenviron, function(s) ROC(Ad(s), type="discrete"))
ReturnsDF <- as.data.table(do.call(merge.xts, Returns))
# adjust column names 
colnames(ReturnsDF) <- gsub(".Adjusted","",colnames(ReturnsDF))
ReturnsDF <- as.data.table(ReturnsDF)
```

However, to make it more robust towards noisy influence of pennystock data I wonder, how its possible to exclude stocks that once in the time period go below a certain value x, let's say 1€.

I guess, the best thing would be to exclude them before calculating the returns and merge the xts object results or even better, before downloading them with the getSymbols command.
Has anybody an idea how this could work best? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exclude them before calculating the returns. Excluding them before downloading  with the `getSymbols` command as you suggested  does not make sense because if you know it before downloading just do not include them in `Symbols` ! Furthermore you have to decide for what time period you want to apply the trigger value. Do you want to exclude symbols with a value below the trigger on the last trading day, within the last x days or since inception ….

Comment: @hvollmeier thanks for your response. The thing is that I'd like to exclude them with some kind of condition, due to the fact that I want to do large sample size of about 450 stocks. E.g.: if the price goes below 1€ in any trade day during the 10y-period, exclude them for the returns calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- build a price frame of the Adj. closing prices of your symbols
  (I use the `PF` function of the quantmod add-on package `qmao` which has lots of other useful functions for this type of analysis. (`install.packages("qmao", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org”)`)
- check by column if any price is below your minimum trigger price
- select only columns which have no closings below the trigger price

To stay more flexible I would suggest to take a sub period - let’s say no price below 5 during the last 21 trading days.The toy example below may illustrate my point.

I use AAPL, FB and MSFT as the symbol universe.

```
> symbols <- c('AAPL','MSFT','FB')
> getSymbols(symbols, from='2018-02-01')
[1] "AAPL" "MSFT" "FB"  
> prices <- PF(symbols, silent = TRUE)
> prices
               AAPL     MSFT     FB
2018-02-01 167.0987 93.81929 193.09
2018-02-02 159.8483 91.35088 190.28
2018-02-05 155.8546 87.58855 181.26
2018-02-06 162.3680 90.90299 185.31
2018-02-07 158.8922 89.19102 180.18
2018-02-08 154.5200 84.61253 171.58
2018-02-09 156.4100 87.76771 176.11
2018-02-12 162.7100 88.71327 176.41
2018-02-13 164.3400 89.41000 173.15
2018-02-14 167.3700 90.81000 179.52
2018-02-15 172.9900 92.66000 179.96
2018-02-16 172.4300 92.00000 177.36
2018-02-20 171.8500 92.72000 176.01
2018-02-21 171.0700 91.49000 177.91
2018-02-22 172.5000 91.73000 178.99
2018-02-23 175.5000 94.06000 183.29
2018-02-26 178.9700 95.42000 184.93
2018-02-27 178.3900 94.20000 181.46
2018-02-28 178.1200 93.77000 178.32
2018-03-01 175.0000 92.85000 175.94
2018-03-02 176.2100 93.05000 176.62
```

Let’s assume you would like any instrument which traded below 175.40 during the last 6 trading days to be excluded from your analysis :-) . 
As you can see that shall exclude AAPL and FB.

`apply` and the base function `any` applied(!) to a 6-day subset of `prices` will give us exactly what we want. Showing the last 3 days of prices excluding the instruments which did not meet our condition:

```
> tail(prices[,apply(tail(prices),2, function(x) any(x < 175.4)) == FALSE],3)
               FB
2018-02-28 178.32
2018-03-01 175.94
2018-03-02 176.62
```

Comment: That's exactly what I looked for! Indeed, the qma add-on is a quite usefull package. I exactly executed like you described in your example. The only different thing is, I'm having all the xts-objects in an seperate environment, so I execute prices <- PF(Symbols, silent = TRUE, env = myenviron2). It works when I only use the three Symbols you used. But I have about 450 ones. Then the following error pops up: Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent.  Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: my symbols-vector has got the dimension [1:473] and myenviron2 has also the dimension list[473]. Realy don't know the reason for the error due to the fact that the only difference is purely the quantity of ticker symbols.

Comment: The number of columns for prices has to be the same length as the vector of ticker symbols. check: `length(colnames(prices))` and `length(Symbols)`

Comment: I can't generate the price- dataframe due to that warning. So I'm not able to look up the columns' length. When I do silent = FALSE I get the following warnings:1: In PF(Symbols, env = myenviron2) :
  Instrument RBI.VI not found, using contract multiplier of 1
2: In PF(Symbols, env = myenviron2) :
  Instrument C8I.VI not found, using contract multiplier of 1..... maybe this is helpful?

Comment: Again, when I do the following, with less symbols it works: myenviron3 <- new.env()
symbols3 <- c('APC.DE','MSF.DE','FB2A.F')
getSymbols(symbols3, from = as.Date("2007-01-02"), to = as.Date("2016-12-30"), 
                    env = myenviron3, src = "yahoo")

prices <- PF(symbols3, silent = TRUE, env = myenviron3)

Comment: In your example for whatever reason you have kept 1 ticker (`^CDAXX`) outside of your Symbols vector. In that case use ` prices <- PF(c(“^CDAXX”,Symbols), silent = TRUE, env = myenviron)`

Comment: I considered that issue and only took the Symbols from the Symbols vector for "myenvrion2". And the error is still there. Realy strange!

Comment: Now, it got it! forgot the "na.omit = FALSE" command! Obviously I had some Stocks w/o any prices! Sorry for that!